# How to get states of iPhone when app is in background?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need to call chronometer methods for pause and resume or stop the timer.In the following scenarios

1.When app is in background and lock the screen.

2.And also need to call methods when iPhone screen turn on from the background.

I am using Darwin libraries but it is working when Location update is on in background.But with this apple will not approve the app.And i found nothing besides this.

Comment: Background running of app is restricted to app that play music, use location updates, VOIP client, or accessory companion apps. If your app does not fall in these categories you are out of luck and can't run in the background.

Comment: Maybe you can play a SILENT MUSIC in backgroud and repeat it.

Comment: you can handle it by using App state.

Comment: Thanks to all 
@TianGeng i tried to play a background music it working on simulator but not on device neither on older version nor on latest version.
Steps which i used :-
Turn on Background mode > Audio,AirPlay and Picture in Picture

Comment: code used by me
func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
        guard let newURL = url else {
            print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
            return
        }
        do {
            Model.sharedInstance().audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: newURL)
            Model.sharedInstance().audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            Model.sharedInstance().audioPlayer.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
        }
    }